# Loop for counting words with tokenized strings

Tags: c#, .net

Having trouble making a loop to count words in my program. It does work when counting separate words, but when there is multiple spaces in a row, each space after the first initial one is read as a whole word. (According to the coding, the program adds 1 to the word counter for every space).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Split method has an overload that takes a parameter called StringSplitOptions that tells it whether to omit empty parts.

```
string[] words = wordcount2.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```